# Android Tab Custom Style Bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I managed to get custom themes running for Tabs but still got a lil issue.

Anybody knows how to get rid of that little blue line below the TabWidget?

I tried setting backgroundcolors here and there to find out which layout is drawing this line.

[screenshot http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/9044/sc20120322142214.png](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/9044/sc20120322142214.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove this Blue line then insert this attribute to your TabWidget:

```
android:tabStripEnabled=”false”
```